# Passenger / REE can't find rails, it's in the $PATH, what gives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, passenger, ruby-enterprise-edition

I've got a fresh install of Ruby EE (1.8.6-20090610) and Passenger (2.2.5) on Debian Lenny.  REE is installed in /opt/ruby-enterprise and it is added to the $PATH of all users through /etc/environment, and PassengerDefaultUser is set to root.  The problem is when loading a rails app, the Passenger error says the rails 2.3.3 gem is missing.  However it was installed with Passenger and a rails -v as root says it's there.  What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8

should have been

PassengerRuby /opt/ruby-enterprise/bin/ruby